# iOS AutoLayOut UITapGestureRecognizer Weirdness

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uitapgesturerecognizer

Pretty new to programing so I plead for your patience.

Im making a card matching game.

I have 20 UIViews as subviews (Aka cards) added to an UIView superview (playing surface). This superview has default autolayout constraints applied to it. I add UITapGestureRecognizers to all 20 subviews. The tap get recognized when the phone is in protrait, but in landscape, half of my subviews stopped recognizing taps (the defunct ones are all on the right side - don't know if that matter).

Thanks for the help

see pictures
http://i62.tinypic.com/behjjr.png
http://i60.tinypic.com/2cmt7jl.png

this is how i added the UITapGesture:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)cardCollection{
    if (!_cardCollection) {
        _cardCollection=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int index=0; index<[self cardCount]; index++){

        Card *card=[self.game cardAtIndex:index];
        //[self addViewtoCardView: card];

        UIView *cardView;
        cardView=[self displayViewforContent:card];

        [cardView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)]];

        cardView.layer.opaque=NO;

        //this adds to the nsmutablearray
        [self.cardCollection addObject:cardView];
    }
}
return _cardCollection;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that they are not overlapping with each other when rotating?

Comment: This approach is... well, a beginner's approach.  Do some research on UICollectionView (which is ideal for something like this), and CALayer.  You can actually customize the methods found in the following answer using CAGradientLayer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9689832/542400

Comment: @isklikas No, nothing is overlapping

Comment: When do you call the above method? viewDidLoad? Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Is the view stretching with the new orientation? Change the background color of your parent view to make sure that the other views are within its bounds.  Otherwise they won't receive touches.  If you're adding them to your viewController's main view, try adding.

```
self.view.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```